# Difference in printing items of iterable

Tags: python

I am new to python. Why is there difference between the below given codes:

Code 1

```
iterable=filter(lambda x:x%2!=0,range(15))
print(i for i in iterable)
```

It gives:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f23e37f35f0>
```

Code 2:

```
iterable=filter(lambda x:x%2!=0,range(15))
for i in iterable:
    print(i)
```

It gives:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
```

I believed both of these printing methods were same till now. Why is there a difference in the outputs?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you believe they are the same? Has anyone ever taught you that?

Comment: Printing integers vs printing a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/), they are not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(i for i in iterable)
```

In this line, the `i for i in iterable` is a generator-expression i.e. an expression that results in a generator when evaluated.

The result you see is the generator that was created by the expression. Generators are lazily evaluated. They yield values when you iterate over them. So `print()` on a generator doesn't yield the values immediately.

```
for i in iterable:
    print(i)
```

Here you are iterating over an iterable & printing each value individually, which means you get all the values in the result. There is no other generator involved.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the first example, you're not looping over the individual items of an iterable to `print()` them one by one; instead, you're using comprehension to create an iterable and `print()` the entire iterable.